# How do I add a counter in my javascript game?

Tags: javascript, html, 2d

I got this game coded in Javascript:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    canv = document.getElementById("gc");
    ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);
    setInterval(game, 1000 / 7);
}

px = py = 10;
gs = tc = 27;
ax = ay = 15;
xv = yv = 0;
trail = [];
tail = 2;

function game () {
    px += xv;
    py += yv;
    if (px < 0) {
        px = tc - 1;
    }
    if (px > tc - 1) {
        px = 0;
    }
    if (py < 0) {
        py = tc-1;
    }
    if (py > tc - 1) {
        py = 0;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
 
    ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
    for(var i = 0; i < trail.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x * gs, trail[i].y * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);
        if (trail[i].x == px && trail[i].y == py) {
            tail = 2;
        }
    }
    trail.push({ x: px, y: py });
    while(trail.length > tail) {
        trail.shift();
    }
 
    if (ax == px && ay == py) {
        tail++;
        ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
        ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(ax * gs, ay * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);
}

function keyPush(evt) {
    switch(evt.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            xv = -1; yv = 0;
            break;
        case 38:
            xv = 0; yv = -1;
            break;
        case 39:
            xv = 1; yv = 0;
            break;
        case 40:
            xv = 0; yv = 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gc" width="729" height="729"></canvas>
```

And I want to add a counter anywhere on the page, so it counts how long the "tail" is.
I have tried a little myself but it doesn't seem to work, any ideas how I should do?

Also another question... how do I change the code with a button or text field on a webpage? Like for example changing:
setInterval(game,1000/7);
to
setInterval(game,1000/9);
with a button or a text field, where you can type the numbers and it gets pasted into the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And i want to add a counter anywhere on the page, so it counts how
> long the "tail" is. I have tried a little myself but it dosen't seem
> to work, any ideas how i do?

For this question, you can add an element to the page and then update it's text in javascript each time the tail changes length (using the `innerText` property of the element).

Sample html element:

```
<!-- inside the body element -->
<div>
    <span>Tail Count: </span>
    <span id="tail-counter">2</span>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
while (trail.length > tail) {
    trail.shift();
    document.getElementById("tail-counter").innerText = tail;
}

if (ax == px && ay == py) {
    tail++;
    document.getElementById("tail-counter").innerText = tail;
    ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
}
```

> Also another queston... how do i change the code with a button or text
> field on a webpage? Like for example changing
> setInterval(game,1000/7); to setInterval(game,1000/9); with a button
> or a text field, where you can type the numbers and it gets pasted
> into the code?

For this question, to change the code based on a text field, you need to first add the text field to the page:

```
<div>
    <span>Set Game Speed: </span>
    <input id="game-speed" type="number" value="7" />
</div>
```

Then you can use javascript to get the value of the text field and use it in your code

```
game_speed = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById("game-speed").value);
interval = setInterval(game, 1000 / game_speed);
```

Now all together (note that this code allows you to change the game speed while playing. This is done by clearing the interval you already made with `clearInterval` and then setting a new interval with the new game speed)

```html
<canvas id="gc" width="729" height="729"></canvas>

<body style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">
    <div>
        <span>Tail Count: </span>
        <span id="tail-counter">2</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Set Game Speed: </span>
        <input id="game-speed" type="number" value="7" />
    </div>

</body>
<script>
    px = py = 10;
    gs = tc = 27;
    ax = ay = 15;
    xv = yv = 0;
    trail = [];
    tail = 2;
    game_speed = 7;
    interval = {};

    window.onload = function () {
        canv = document.getElementById("gc");
        ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);

        game_speed = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById("game-speed").value);
        interval = setInterval(game, 1000 / game_speed);
    }

    function game() {

        let new_speed = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById("game-speed").value);
        if (new_speed !== game_speed) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            game_speed = new_speed;
            interval = setInterval(game, 1000 / game_speed);
        }

        px += xv;
        py += yv;
        if (px < 0) {
            px = tc - 1;
        }
        if (px > tc - 1) {
            px = 0;
        }
        if (py < 0) {
            py = tc - 1;
        }
        if (py > tc - 1) {
            py = 0;
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
        for (var i = 0; i < trail.length; i++) {
            ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x * gs, trail[i].y * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);
            if (trail[i].x == px && trail[i].y == py) {
                tail = 2;
            }
        }
        trail.push({
            x: px,
            y: py
        });
        while (trail.length > tail) {
            trail.shift();
            document.getElementById("tail-counter").innerText = tail;
        }

        if (ax == px && ay == py) {
            tail++;
            document.getElementById("tail-counter").innerText = tail;
            ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
            ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(ax * gs, ay * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);
    }

    function keyPush(evt) {
        switch (evt.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                xv = -1;
                yv = 0;
                break;
            case 38:
                xv = 0;
                yv = -1;
                break;
            case 39:
                xv = 1;
                yv = 0;
                break;
            case 40:
                xv = 0;
                yv = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use predefined value as you setInterval timer, all you need to do is to find your best method of getting user inputs, e.g using an `input box`. Then you can grab the value with `javascript`

E.g

```
[HTML]
<input type="number" value="500" id="num">
```

````
[JS]

let num = document.getElementById('num').value;
num = +num; //cast the value to number since its returned as a string.

setInterval(game, num/nth); //nth is any value of your choice, or you can also grab from user input
```

For your first question, getting how long the tail is depends on how you want it.
you can use a variable and always increment it, each time your code condition is met.
````

Comment: you can use `fillText(text, x, y)` browse more about it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to write the trail length in the canvas, I added to your code

```
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillText(trail.length, 100, 100);
ctx.font = "bold 20px sans-serif";
ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
```

that way it constantly prints the trail length at the top left corner.
and as for your second question, I added the intervalTime variable at the global scope so you could change it and then the next interval will be in the time you entered to that variable.

```js
var intervalTime = 1000/7;

window.onload=function() {
    canv=document.getElementById("gc");
    ctx=canv.getContext("2d");
    document.addEventListener("keydown",keyPush);
    
    setInterval(game, intervalTime);
}

px=py=10;
gs=tc=27;
ax=ay=15;
xv=yv=0;
trail=[];
tail = 2;

function game() {
    px+=xv;
    py+=yv;
    if(px<0) {
        px= tc-1;
    }
    if(px>tc-1) {
        px= 0;
    }
    if(py<0) {
        py= tc-1;
    }
    if(py>tc-1) {
        py= 0;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canv.width,canv.height);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillText(trail.length, 100, 100);
    ctx.font = "bold 20px sans-serif";
    ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
 
    ctx.fillStyle="lime";
    for(var i=0;i<trail.length;i++) {
        ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x*gs,trail[i].y*gs,gs-2,gs-2);
        if(trail[i].x==px && trail[i].y==py) {
            tail = 2;
        }
    }
    trail.push({x:px,y:py});
    while(trail.length>tail) {
    trail.shift();
    }
 
    if(ax==px && ay==py) {
        tail++;
        ax=Math.floor(Math.random()*tc);
        ay=Math.floor(Math.random()*tc);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.fillRect(ax*gs,ay*gs,gs-2,gs-2);
}

function keyPush(evt) {
    switch(evt.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            xv=-1;yv=0;
            break;
        case 38:
            xv=0;yv=-1;
            break;
        case 39:
            xv=1;yv=0;
            break;
        case 40:
            xv=0;yv=1;
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gc" width="729" height="729"></canvas>
```